# Can't load image using openImageIO

Tags: c++, openimageio

I was trying to load image using opeimageio which I installed using vcpkg. But I get an error saying F:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\OpenImageIO\fmt\format-inl.h(1371,8): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'HANDLE'. My code is this

```
#include <OpenImageIO/imageio.h>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

std::tuple<int, int, int> loadImageFromFile(std::string_view filePath,
                                            std::vector<unsigned char> &data) {  auto input = OIIO::ImageInput::open(filePath.data());
  auto &specs = input->spec();
  int width = specs.width;
  int height = specs.height;
  int channels = specs.nchannels;
  data = std::vector<unsigned char>(width * height * channels);
  input->read_image(OIIO::TypeDesc::UINT8, &data[0]);
  input->close();
  return {width, height, channels};
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you need to include windows.h before that header for some reason. `HANDLE`  is from winapi.

Comment: @drescherjm  I have tried It but It is still the same. In fact imageio.h  includes windows.h

Comment: You probably want to file a bug report at the github page for vcpkg